# Why doesn't this component show at all? React DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

Here is the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

class DatePickerCreater extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DatePicker
                disabled={this.props.answer.isDisabled}
                dateFormat="YYYY/MM/DD"
                selected={Date(this.props.answer.value)}
                onChange={(e) => this.props.blurHandler(e.target.value,this.props.answer)} 
            />
        );
    }
}

export default DatePickerCreater
```

when i try to render it, it shows nothing...

***Very grateful for every answer!***

Comment: I can only see a `jsx` snippet. Where is the component?

Comment: the jsx snippet is the whole component. I've imported the component from 'react-datepicker' so it's not my component, I've cut out the rest of the code the class defenition and export just to make it easier

Comment: Then please do not omit crucial parts of your component. The problem may be in that part. You can leave out imports and exports if you like to keep it simple.

Comment: I know that dude... as I wrote before, I did just put the relevant information here. There's nothing wrong with my component, only this part. I'll add some example code so you understand how it looks partly

Comment: You say it doesn't render so maybe there is something wrong. So please if you post a component, post the whole code so that others can see if there is something wrong or not.

Comment: If that is your `constructor` it will not work. The constructor takes `props` as an argument and calls `super()` with it.

Comment: Is there any error in your console or does it just not render?

Comment: It just doesn't render.. :/

Comment: Can you confirm, that your `DatePickerCreater` component is actually getting rendered by its parent? Because there seems to be nothing wrong except that you need to pass a moment.js date as `selected` prop.

Comment: yeah I saw that too, and i can confirm that it is getting rendered, because I can see the div that has built there and also if I add random things they are shown

Comment: If you wrap the contents of your `return` with a div and put other content in that div as a sibling to your datepicker, do you see that content?

Comment: Did you forget to import the css file? See my updated answer.

Comment: How are you compiling your output code? Can you confirm that you are running the correctly compiled code? What is the div that has been built? How do you know it is the date picker component that has rendered this? Install React dev tools to chrome and get some more insights into what is going on.

Comment: I created a codesandbox example with your code and it renders correctly: https://codesandbox.io/s/4zj6j0pvq7. Only difference is I imported the css file. Don't know if you did.

Comment: By doesn't render you mean there is nothing there when you inspect the page, i.e. no elements of that component are rendered? Or do you mean it doesn't visibly show up?

Comment: Added the css file but nothing changed.. I Will check the data coming from the api tomorrow, thanks for all the responses wow guys! I’ll be in touch tomorrow when I get back into this. Will check with React developer tools for chrome I have it, but haven’t learned how to use it yet..

Comment: Also just follow some very basic steps. Change to just returning `<h1>Hello World</h1>` if that doesn't render, then you have bigger issues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `selected` property takes a `moment.js` date, not a plain javascript date. You should get an error that says "date.clone is not a function
". You can fix that by using a moment date:

```
import moment from 'moment';

class DatePickerCreater extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <DatePicker
                disabled={this.props.answer.isDisabled}
                dateFormat="YYYY/MM/DD"
                selected={moment(this.props.answer.value)}
                onChange={(e) => this.props.blurHandler(e.target.value, this.props.answer)}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Also you may have forgotten to import the `react-datepicker` css file. Without that the popup will not show correctly:

```
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
```

### EDIT

Since they switched to using `date-fns` this answer is outdated. **If you are using `react-date-picker` with a version `>=2.0` you can no longer pass a `moment.js` instance**. Instead use native `Date` objects and manipulate them using [`date-fns`](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns).

For Reference:

> Up until version 1.8.0, this package was using Moment.js. Starting
>   v2.0.0, we switched to using date-fns, which uses native Date objects,
>   to reduce the size of the package. If you're switching from 1.8.0 to
>   2.0.0 or higher, please see the updated example above of check out the [examples site](https://reactdatepicker.com/) for up to date examples.

---

Comment: This is probably true, and I changed it. But it still doesn't show :/

Comment: In 2019, after they replaced `moment.js` with `date-fns` this still helped me. I had forgotten to import the .css (even though it's explicitly shown in the example on [GitHub](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) )

Comment: Thomas is right - passing `moment.js` value to `selected` will crash the app nowadays

Comment: @Skypho I updated the answer to reflect this. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Importing the CSS was the key for me

Answer (score 0):

The code is not enough, what can I tell super() need to be called with props:

```js
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   // ... code
}
```

Comment: yeah, fixed that, but doesn't solve my problem :/ What more do you need? Tell me and I'll add it. What I can see, this is the only thing relevant for the datepicker component, isn't it?

Comment: Show me how do you render class DatePickerCreater in its parent